# Why does Elasticsearch2 Adapter gives a 'cannot connect to any node' while trying to connect to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-calcite

I am using elasticsearch version-6.1.1.I have downloaded the calcite framework project and build it in my machine following the tutorial at (https://calcite.apache.org/docs/tutorial.html) and when i tried to connect to elasticsearch using the Elasticsearch2adaptor of calcite as given here(https://calcite.apache.org/docs/elasticsearch_adapter.html).i'm getting the following error
**ERROR:**

```
*E:\calcite\elasticsearch2>sqlline
sqlline version 1.3.0
sqlline> !connect jdbc:calcite:model=target/test-classes/mymodel.json admin admin
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Connecting to jdbc:calcite:model=target/test-classes/mymodel.json
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error instantiating JsonCustomSchema(name=elasticsearch)
at org.apache.calcite.model.ModelHandler.visit(ModelHandler.java:275)
at org.apache.calcite.model.JsonCustomSchema.accept(JsonCustomSchema.java:45)
at org.apache.calcite.model.ModelHandler.visit(ModelHandler.java:196)
at org.apache.calcite.model.ModelHandler.<init>(ModelHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver$1.onConnectionInit(Driver.java:104)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:139)
at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:156)
at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:204)
at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1095)
at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:791)
at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ***Cannot connect to any elasticsearch nodes***
at org.apache.calcite.adapter.elasticsearch2.Elasticsearch2Schema.open(Elasticsearch2Schema.java:123)
at org.apache.calcite.adapter.elasticsearch2.Elasticsearch2Schema.<init>(Elasticsearch2Schema.java:73)
at org.apache.calcite.adapter.elasticsearch2.Elasticsearch2SchemaFactory.create(Elasticsearch2SchemaFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.calcite.model.ModelHandler.visit(ModelHandler.java:270)
... 18 more*
```

This is mymodel.json file:

```
{
    "version":"1.0",
    "defaultSchema":"elasticsearch",
    "schemas": [
    {
        "type" : "custom",
        "name" : "elasticsearch",
        "factory" : "org.apache.calcite.adapter.elasticsearch2.Elasticsearch2SchemaFactory",
        "operand" : {
            "coordinates" : "{'127.0.0.1':9300}",
            "userConfig" : "{'bulk.flush.max.actions':10 , 'bulk.flush.max.size.mb': 1}",
            "index" : "movies"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter mentioned by you is not compatible with Elasticsearch 6.x

Quoting from web page of the adapter

> This adapter is targeted for Elasticsearch 2.x. To use Calcite with
>   Elasticsearch 5.x+ you can use the factory of the adapter targeted for
>   Elasticsearch 5.x:

You can downgrade the Elasticsearch to version 2.x or 5.x, and it should work

Comment: Is that the only option?Isn't there any adapter for elasticsearch 6.x

Comment: I also tried it with elasticsearch5adaptor,but getting the same error as 'connot connect to any elasticsearch node'

Comment: Nobody has created the adapter for elasticsearch 6.x. If you are using elasticsearch5adaptor, you need to use elasticsearch 5.x, and if you are using elasticsearch2adaptor, you need to use elasticsearch 2.x

Comment: Thanks for the response @JSas,i'll downgrade my elasticsearh and try it.

Comment: yeah it is working with lower version.Thank a lot JSas